# Ruby "man" docs- multi-line comments using "\"?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading Ruby's "man" page, and I see the following description of the "-S" flag:

```
-S   Makes Ruby use the PATH environment variable to search for script, unless its name begins with a slash.  This is used to emulate #! on
     machines that don't support it, in the following manner:

           #! /usr/local/bin/ruby
           # This line makes the next one a comment in Ruby \
           exec /usr/local/bin/ruby -S $0 $*

     On some systems $0 does not always contain the full pathname, so you need the -S switch to tell Ruby to search for the script if necessary
     (to handle embedded spaces and such).  A better construct than $* would be ${1+"$@"}, but it does not work if the script is being
     interpreted by csh(1).
```

The part I'm confused about is this part:

```
# This line makes the next one a comment in Ruby \
exec /usr/local/bin/ruby -S $0 $*
```

This sounds like the `man` entry is saying that the `\` character causes the line after it to be treated as a comment.

To test this, I tried making a new Ruby script named "foo.rb", which includes these two lines, and a simple "puts" statement:

```
# This line makes the next one a comment in Ruby \
exec /usr/bin/env ruby -S $0 $*

puts "Hi"
```

I changed the script from `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to `/usr/bin/env ruby` because I don't have a `ruby` executable located at `/usr/local/bin`.  I don't think that should affect the outcome in a meaningful way, because (according to the docs) that line should be treated as a comment, not as executable code.

If my interpretation of the `man` entry were correct, I'd expect to see `Hi` output to the terminal when I run "ruby foo.rb".  But that's not what happens.  Instead, I see the following:

```
$ ruby foo.rb
foo.rb:2: unknown regexp option - b
exec /usr/bin/env ruby -S $0 $*
foo.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
exec /usr/bin/env ruby -S $0 $*
foo.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected global variable, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
exec /usr/bin/env ruby -S $0 $*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm... that backslash-in-line-comment trick is not one I've ever seen in Ruby, and it doesn't seem to work for me either. It's also not referenced in the [official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/comments_rdoc.html) for comments. I wonder if the man page is outdated...

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that confused me as well.  I was similarly unable to find relevant docs for making a multi-line comment in Ruby using the `\\` character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this specific part of Ruby's man page is severely outdated. In fact, it was originally added [in the first (data) commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3db12e8b236ac8f88db8eb4690d10e4a3b8dbcd4/ruby.1#L278-L295) to Ruby's (then) SVN repository.

At that time, apparently Ruby's parser did [indeed support](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3db12e8b236ac8f88db8eb4690d10e4a3b8dbcd4/parse.y#L1980-L1992) line continuations with a backslash at the end of a comment as shown in the syntax example of the man page.

This feature was removed however from Ruby on March 2, 1999 in [SVN revision 520](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/65a5162550f58047974793cdc8067a970b2435c0#diff-60e6f0aa6e190c54f6cb0ac74148ced3cf0ef8703e1c3824a07a82dc54654953) (the diff is quite large and is not rendered by default in GitHub; check line 2433 of the `parse.y` file).

The [ChangeLog entry](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/65a5162550f58047974793cdc8067a970b2435c0/ChangeLog#L1367-L1370) for that change reads:

```
Tue Mar  2 17:04:19 1999  Yukihiro Matsumoto  <matz@netlab.co.jp>

    * parse.y (yylex): backslashes do not concatenate comment lines
      anymore.
```

This change was released with Ruby 1.4.0 in August 1999. Since that time, more than 24 years ago, the example from the man page did not work anymore.

Later (but still quite old) documentation [suggests a different approach](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/options.html):

```rb
#!/bin/sh
exec ruby -S -x $0 "$@"
#! ruby
puts 'Hello World'
```

Here, the `exec` is always executed and you still use the `-S` flag to execute the current file in the Ruby interpreter. However, we also use the `-x` flag which instructs Ruby to skip all lines from the file until it finds a line containing `#!ruby` (or apparently `#! ruby`). This does still work today.

Comment: Confirmed that this works on my machine.  TY.

Comment: Excellent GitHub research!